# Adding jQuery libraries using #attached library and drupal_add_js

Tags: forms, javascript

> version: drupal7.23

I have a web page include 2+ jQuery version libraries, at the page's search box, I use `$form['#attached']['library'][] = array('system' => 'ui.autocomplete')` to get autocomplete effect, it's works well, besides the page I mentioned at the beginning.

But when I replace `#attached` into `drupal_add_js('/path/to/3party/autocomplete.js')`, it's works well for all pages.

I've tried using `$.noConflict()` but still not working, can someone tell me why ?